# Trying to import sprintf javascript function into an Ionic application

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, typescript-typings

I created a basic `Ionic` application with the typical command:

```
$ ionic start myApp tabs
```

Then I wanna use inside `home.ts` the function: `sprintf`.

Then, as recommended on:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/javascript-libraries-in-a-typescript-application-revisited/

I did:

```
$ npm install sprintf-js --save # there they use: "base-64" instead of "sprintf"
```

At the begining of the file: `home.ts` I did:

```
var sprintf = require('sprintf-js');
```

Also, as recommended there, in order to make use of: `require`, I did:

```
npm install @types/node --save
```

But when compiling I get:

```
$ ionic build android --debug

[12:50:58]  typescript: D:/myApp/src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 6  MEM: 184.0MB
            Cannot find name 'require'.

       L6:  var sprintf = require('sprintf-js');
```

Any idea on this?